# How to combine logical operation in RTF file?

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle

I have a report that checks on workflow assignee, and we need to print that assignee name on Custom Print. The application is Unifier, and CP developed using an internal data model using BI publisher desktop.

My condition was

> <?IF:(STEP_NAME= 'Design - Road' OR STEP_NAME= 'Design - Bridge' OR
>   STEP_NAME='Bridge Management' OR STEP_NAME= 'Traffic Operations'  OR
>   STEP_NAME= 'Traffic Engineering' OR STEP_NAME= 'Materials' OR
>   STEP_NAME= 'Other') AND STEP_ACTION='Return to AE' AND
>   STEP_STATUS='Completed' "?>

but with that, it does not print the assignee name.

How would I be able to combine the logical operators in rtf template?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unifier is an Oracle technology. You would probably get more feedback if you tagged your question with `oracle` instead of `sql-server` (which is a Microsoft SQL Server).